# Jupyter Notebook does not open browser after changing the default browser

Tags: python, internet-explorer, firefox, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

The default browser for my Jupyter Notebook was Internet Explorer and it was working fine with that. I have windows 10. I changed the default browser to Firefox by following steps in this website :

https://support.anaconda.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024044333-Change-default-browser-in-Jupyter-Notebook

However now the notebook does not start automatically in Firefox and it tells me to copy and paste:

> Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first
>   time,

Can anyone tell me how to open Jupyter Notebook automatically in Firefox since above were the steps recommended by anaconda website. By the way after copying and pasting the link in the Firefox I can open notebook fine. I just need to know how to ask notebook to open automatically in Firefox like it was working in Internet Explorer.

Comment: What happens if you use `jupyter notebook --debug` to launch the notebook? It should provide some useful information.

Comment: did you activate the line you edited ?

Comment: or post the line you are using to change the default browser

Comment: Yes uncomment the lines (if it is what you mean by activation),

Comment: @Allaye, c.NotebookApp.browser = u'Firefox path %s'

Answer (score 0):

c.NotebookApp.browser = u'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'

make sure you remove the hash(#) before the c.Notebookapp, and your escape key

Comment: I removed the # but what do you mean by escape key ?

Comment: i mean forward slash